# Will webP animated images in a Flutter app show on iOS?

Tags: image, flutter, webp

That's it really.  Are webPs robust on ios?

Couldn't find an answer readily.  For animations, I love webp's reduction, but I can't be having with all those callbacks like in HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Webp isn’t supported at all in iOS. You have to use .jp2 format.

I don’t know if .jp2 does what you need.

Comment: Update: webp is now supported on iOS